# how to retrieve attribute data-id values ​without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How do I retrieve all data-id attribute values? I have tried using jquery but only 1 id or 1 value is obtained

**for my code**

```
 <div class="col text-right mr-1">
    <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" id="show_more" data-idpost="<?= $p["id_post"] ?>">show more comments</a>
 </div>
```

**jquery**

```
var id = $(".show_more").data("idpost");
console.log(id)
```

**the results that I got**
[but only 1 id or 1 value is obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUlER.png)

Comment: This behaviour shouldn't be a surprise! https://api.jquery.com/data/ "*return the value at the named data store for the **first element** in the set of matched elements*"

Answer (score 1):

To build an array of the `data-idpost` values from all `.show-more` elements you can use `map()`:

```js
var idData = $('.show_more').map((i, el) => el.dataset.idpost).get();
console.log(idData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col text-right mr-1">
  <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" id="show_more" data-idpost="1">show more comments</a>
</div>
<div class="col text-right mr-1">
  <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" id="show_more" data-idpost="2">show more comments</a>
</div>
<div class="col text-right mr-1">
  <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" id="show_more" data-idpost="3">show more comments</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `show_more` class as multiple .You could use with [`Jquery#map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and `jquery.get()` api method

```js
var ids = $(".show_more").map((i,elem)=> $(elem).data("idpost")).get()
console.log(ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col text-right mr-1">
    <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" data-idpost="1">show more comments</a>
    <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom"  data-idpost="2">show more comments</a>
    <a href="" class="show_more comment-count-custom" data-idpost="3">show more comments</a>
 </div>
```